# what does it mean, "foot up" as verb?

Tags: grammar, differences, word-usage

I'm just guessing "foot up" means "kick something up"? Can I say "do it , or foot up your face"?
Thanks,

Comment: What made you think this is a normal English phrase? 'Just guessing'?

Comment: Please provide the context where you found this phrase, e.g. a quoted passage, a comic panel, a street sign.

Answer (score 1):

OED doesn't list *foot up* as a verb at all, but it does have it as a noun:

> **foot-up**   *n. Rugby football* in scrummaging, the illegal lifting of either foot by any member of the front row of forwards on either side before the ball is put in the scrummage.
>
> > 1921   E. H. D. Sewell *Rugby Football* 361   Inadvertent offside, foot-up,..are..absolutely unavoidable at times.
> > 1963   *Times* 7 Mar. 3/5   For a foot-up offence, MacCormac...got three points for the Pay Corps.

I suppose it's possible to verbify a noun, and to create a verb *foot up* which means "to lift a foot against the rules of Rugby football," but it would only have that specific use.

The threat proposed in the question would be more likely to use ***in*** than *up*:

> Do it, or you'll get a foot in your face.

Answer (score 0):

*To foot up* has something to do with accumulating costs. For example,

> His debts *foot up * to a huge sum.

meaning, that the debts had accumulated into a huge sum of money.

Hope that helps